# Laravel - Class not found in Package (only on Linux)

Tags: php, linux, laravel, laravel-5, psr-4

I created a package of name *Getbit\Emojione* and set in composer.json, from Laravel root project.

[image: psr-4 package path]

In package folder I added some classes and defined the psr-4

[image]

This is the Client Class

[image: package folder]

The problem happens in the line 19, I get a Class Not Found, but only in Linux, I know Linux is case sensitive, but every path seems to be correct

[image: My Client Class]

The error:

[image: Error Class not found]

Comment: clean cache and try again

Comment: I already did that @DanyalSandeelo

Comment: `new Client()` c is capital right?

Comment: @DanyalSandeelo, yes my class name is "Client"

Comment: how about writing src in the namespace? tried that? since I can see SRC before Api folder

Comment: Add namespace correctly. I think it would be like getbit\emojione\src\Api

Comment: try $client = new \Client();